# ARM Cortex A8 PMNC read gives 0 after enabling also.. Any Idea/Suggestions?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module, cpu-registers, cortex-a8

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("user-mode access to performance registers");

int __init arm_init(void)

{
    unsigned int value;

    /* enable user-mode access */
    printk(KERN_INFO "enable user-mode access\n");
    asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 0\n\t" :: "r"(1));

    /* Reading the value here--just to check */

    asm ("MRC p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0\t\n": "=r"(value));
    printk("value: %d\n", value);


    /* disable counter overflow interrupts (just in case)*/
    printk(KERN_INFO "disable counter overflow interrupts (just in case)\n");
    asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 2\n\t" :: "r"(0x8000000f));

    printk(KERN_INFO "user-mode access to performance registers enabled\n");
    return 0;
}


void arm_exit(void)
{
    unsigned int value;
    asm ("MRC p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0\t\n": "=r"(value));
    printk("value: %d\n", value);
    printk(KERN_INFO "user-mode access to performance registers disabled\n");
}

module_init(arm_init);
module_exit(arm_exit);
```

In init module read gives 1, but in cleanup module reading the variable gives 0.
Any idea how does it get updated ?

Comment: From the [tag:linux-kernel] info, *Since the internals of the Linux kernel are constantly changing, it is helpful to include the precise kernel version(s) that you are interested in.*

Comment: Thank you Bill !!
how would you define including precise kernel version ?

Comment: Is it an Android, Linaro or Linux mainline kernel. The version is typically *3.8.3* or something like that.  The latest version is *3.9-rc3*.  It looks like there has been some *churn* recently in the `perf_event` infra-structure which touches some of these `MCR/MRC` registers.  See http://www.kernel.org

Comment: Thank you Bil !!

kernel version and details:
its Linux mainline 3.0.20 and little changes(say 3.0.20+). I am sure these changes are not reflected to PMNC or CCNT.