# Profling on arm Cortex_A8

Tags: c, linux, arm, profiler, cortex-a8

I want to do profiling for my application on ARM processor. I found the oprofile doesn't work. Someone used the following code to test a few years ago. the cyclic counter 
does work, the performance monitor counter still doesn't work. I tested it again, it is same. For following code, I got cycle count: 2109, performance monitor count: 0. I have searched by google, so far, I have not found a solution. Has someone fixed this issue?

```
    uint32_t value = 0
    uint32_t count = 0;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timezone tz;

    // enable all counters
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 1" ::"r" (0x8000000f));

    // select counter 0,
    __asm__ __volatile__("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 5" ::"r" (0x0));
    // select event
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 1" ::"r"(0x57));

    // reset all counters to ero and enable all counters
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" : "=r" (value));
    value |= 0xF;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" :: "r" (value));

    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);

    __asm__ __volatile__("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r" (count));
    printf("cycle count: %d", count);

    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mrc P15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 2": "=r" (count));
    printf("performance monitor count: %d", count);
```

Comment: You are using either [tag:android] or [tag:linux-kernel].  Please tag your question appropriately.  Also, provide a version.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492120/arm-cortex-a8-pmnc-read-gives-0-after-enabling-also-any-idea-suggestions

Comment: Apparently you have to use `asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 0\n\t" :: "r"(1));` in kernel space to enable user-mode access.  Is this the problem?

Comment: I use linux kernel 2.6.32. No problem to enable user-mode in user space, I use __asm__ __volatile__ ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" : "=r" (value)); to check, it is in user mode. I don't need to write
it.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, and in my case it was due to the `NIDENm` signal being pulled low.

From the ARM documentation:

> The PMU only counts events when non-invasive debug is enabled, that is, when either `DBGENm` or `NIDENm` inputs are asserted. The Cycle Count (PMCCNTR) Register is always enabled regardless of whether non-invasive debug is enabled, unless the DP bit of the PMCR register is set.

That **NIDENm** signal is an input to the ARM core, so exactly how it is controlled will depend on the parts of the processor external to the core.  In my case, I found a register controlling NIDEN.  In your case, it may be a register, or a pin, or (possibly) the signal is just pulled low and you can't use the feature.

Also from the ARM documentation:

> The values of the `DBGENm` and `NIDENm` signals can be determined by polling `DBGDSCR[17:16]`, `DBGDSCR[15:14]`, or the `DBGAUTHSTATUS`.

So, if you can read one of those, you can confirm that the problem is **NIDENm**.